# Multiplicative order

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I tried to learn about the multiplicative order from different sources, but I want to get sure that I understand it well...

As I understand, if we define to numbers, $a \in \Bbb Z$, $n \in \Bbb N^+$, where $a$, $n$ are coprime, then $O_n(a)$ is the smallest positive integer $k$ such that $a^k\;\mathrm{mod}\;n = 1$.
Is this true?

Comment: You mean "the order of $\;a\pmod n=$ the order of $\;a\;$ in the multiplicative group of units modulo $\;n\;$ ...? If so then yes: that is true, though I'd rather write (for clearity)  $$a^k=1\pmod n$$

Comment: so it is written like $a^k\equiv 1\pmod n$

Comment: Two, three lines...who cares? The meaning in both cases is, I think, clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, that's it.

As $1,a,a^2,a^3,\dots$ is a *periodic sequence* mod $m$ if $\gcd(a,m)=1$, the smallest $k$ with $a^k\equiv 1 \pmod m$ coincides with the number of elements of
$$\{a^n\,\text{mod}\, m\mid n\in\Bbb N\}\,.$$